# Ubuntu Server | Gateway: 0.0.0.0

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, static-ip, samba4

I am trying to setup an Ubuntu Server (non-graphical). However when I try to assign a Static IP address to the device instead of the default DHCP -- the system keeps telling me that the gateway is `0.0.0.0` (undefined) and as a result, my attempt to change my IP address fails.

If any of you guys have experienced something similar to this, I would appreciate the help.

PS - I am testing this using a Virtual computer, in addition the virtual computer is connect via WiFi. I understand this is not the best connection method, however I simply want to get a feel for the process before I commit to the real deal.

Answer (score 0):

You have nice manual for server network configuration [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic).

Also you can add default gw with fallowing command

```
sudo route add default gw ip_address_of_gw
```

This command is only a temporary solution, until you restart server.

Comment: I get the following response: `siocaddrt: network is unreachable`